# How do I prevent a menu extra from appearing at login?

Tags: menu-bar

Recently I reinstalled OS X 10.6.8 and afterwards I removed my DVD drive since it was no necessary. However, upon booting the 'eject' menu extra appears. Dragging it off does not help as it reappears during the next boot. There are no other drives removable connected.

Is there any simple solution other than deleting the menu extra file?
(Though it is a wonderful application, using Bartender is not a solution.)

Comment: Can you post the screenshot please.

Comment: @AbhishekSalian http://cl.ly/O4T6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> http://macs.about.com/od/macoperatingsystems/qt/ejectcdmenu.htm

or

Rename eject.menu in /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/ to something else "eject.menu.bak"

restart mac and then rename the file back to original.

Not sure if it works but trying doesnt hurt anyone.

Comment: Renaming it didn't have any ill effect upon boot so I think I'll just keep it as 'Eject.menu.bak' since I don't ever plan on using this particular menu extra.
Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your solution of CMD-Click&Drag to remove the menu extra should resolve your issue, and the item should not reappear at login.  I would investigate other potential causes of this issue.

First I would repair permissions.